# Can not display error in both places with same code

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display error in case of `empty` field. Had two seperate  fields, one is input and the other one is `textarea`. For some reason, functionality works fine with `textarea` itself but not in input. First condition of if statement in `inputName` applies as I can see it when I provide no info but else statement doesn't apply. What might be possible thing causing that?

Html:

```
 <input type="text" name="userName" />
        <p class="error">Please add a name.</p>

<textarea placeholder="Write a paragraph about yourself" maxlength="140" name="userDescription"></textarea>
        <p class="error">Please add a short description.</p>
```

JS:

```
let firstError = document.querySelectorAll(".error")[0];
let secondError = document.querySelectorAll(".error")[1];
let inputName = inputs["userName"].value;
let userDescription = document.querySelector("textarea");

f (!document.querySelector("textarea").value) {
    secondError.style.display= "block";
} else {
    secondError.style.display= "none";
}

if (!inputName) {
    firstError.style.display= "block";
} else {
    firstError.style.display= "none"; 
}
```

Comment: Where is inputs declared?

Answer (score 0):

Tried the code, besides "if" statement error (in the given code theres 'f' instead of 'if'), the problem is with inputs[], which I have never saw, except as CSS selector (without 's', though).

Replacing inputs["userName"].value with propper selector (I prefer using document.getElement(s)ById/ByClassName/ByTagName/ByName), everything works as expected.

Though, I'd recommend trying form API, e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation_api.asp or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement, but whatever method is used, it's better to use empty HTML element as a placeholder for error and add error message dynamically by using JS.

The following code is not the best answer, but it does as required with as little changes to the code as possible, for the more proper way, for the start I'd recommend the links provided in the previous paragraph):

```
 <form>
    <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" />
    <p class="error">Please add a name.</p>

    <textarea placeholder="Write a paragraph about yourself" maxlength="140" name="userDescription" id="userDescription"></textarea>
    <p class="error">Please add a short description.</p>

    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="checkInput()">
</form>

<script>
    function checkInput() {
        let firstError = document.querySelectorAll(".error")[0];
        let secondError = document.querySelectorAll(".error")[1];

        let inputName = document.getElementById("userName").value;
        let userDescription = document.getElementById("userDescription").value;

        if (!document.querySelector("textarea")) {
            secondError.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            secondError.style.display = "none";
        }

        if (!inputName) {
            firstError.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            firstError.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [referencing elements using ids](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp) instead of relying on their order in the DOM?

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="userName" />
<p class="error" id=“userNameError”>Please add a name.</p>

<textarea placeholder="Write a paragraph about yourself" maxlength="140" id="userDescription"></textarea>
<p class="error" id="userDescriptionError">Please add a short description.</p>
```

JS:

```
var userName = document.getElementById("userName");
var userDescription = document.getElementById("userDescription");

var userNameError = document.getElementById("userNameError");
var userDescription = document.getElementById("userDescriptionError");

if (userName.value) {
    userNameError.style.display = "none";
}
else {
    userNameError.style.display = "block";
}

if (userDescription.value) {
    userDescriptionError.style.display = "none";
}
else {
    userDescriptionError.style.display = "block";
}
```